# $http in Angular 1.3 Removing Quotes From Response

Tags: angularjs, http

I am upgrading our app from Angular 1.2.29 to 1.3.0. Previously we have an API that simply returns true. In $http response the data was "true" in Angular 1.2.29 and is now only true with no quotes in 1.3.0.  I don't see any mention of this in the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration . Does anyone know of this or have an explanation?

Comment: What does your API response look like, when hit through a client like Postman?

Comment: If I query using Postman all I get as a response is true . No quotes or anything. The content-type is application/json;charset=utf-8

Comment: Probably best if you show us the relevant code. Is it getting stringified anywhere?

Comment: Wait, you were originally working with the string, now you are getting the boolean. Disregard my previous comment about stringifying, but still show us the code.